# Setting Glassfish database from inside application

Tags: database, glassfish

I have a JSF application that uses a simple database for login management. I'm using Oracle Galssfish as server, and after I've done all the necessary configurations on admin console (setting up the driver, connection pools, etc), it's working properly.

However, I was wondering if there is a way to set the connection pool parameters (ip, port, username and password) from inside my application. I can crate all the properties I need on my bean and get/set then just fine, but how do I set them on Glassfish?

Answer (score 1):

You could use AMX (Application Server Management Extenstions):

See https://blogs.oracle.com/JagadishPrasath/entry/creating_jdbc_connection_pool_resource#4_Creating_Connection_Pool__Resource

Comment: That sounds interesting. I will try that and post the results here.